# Xamarin WebView Auth

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a website and I made this website into a mobile application using webview. Everything is perfect. However, the Google and Facebook login buttons on my website do not work in my mobile application with webview. I don't get any response when I press these buttons. I would be glad if you could help.

```
<WebView Source="MyWebSiteUrl"/>
```

There is no other code in my app

[my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wer51.png)

Comment: Are you getting any information in the Debug window? Give us something to go on here, there is not enough information in the Question

Comment: No, I don't get any mistakes, that's all I have

Comment: I would like to give more information, but this is all I have. I haven't done much anyway. Do you have any answers?